# Rails - How To Transfer Data With Button Press

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to `Rails`, so this has been tough for me to understand. The front end guy in my group for a school project designed this so that when I tap the "More Info" button on a displayed product, a pop up box shows up on the screen with more information about the product.

How do I make the selected product's info accessible to me so I could display it in the pop up box? I've tried `button_to` with an `:action` but I apparently needs a view template, but I don't want that. I simply want to display the selected product's info in the pop up box that shows up when the user taps the "More Info" button.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
<!-- Container for the Catalog Content -->
<div class="Catalog_page">
    <!-- List all products -->
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <div class="product_item">
            <span class="img"><%= image_tag product.image, size: "200x100" %></span>
            <h1><%= product.name %></h1>
            <!--<%= product.description %> Saved  this just incase we needed it-->
            <%= number_to_currency(product.price) %>
            <!-- Button that creates light box -->
            <button class="lightbox" id="button">More Info</button>
        </div>


    <%end%>
    <!-- backdrop is the black background of lightbox -->
    <div class="backdrop"></div>
    <!-- the box that we need to plug information to -->
    <div class="box"><div class="close"></div>
        I DON'T KNOW HOW TO PULL THIS INFORMATION FROM DATA BASE

    </div> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do your task:

- You can render these "more info" and keep it hidden, and then you show the modal these info.

> ```
> <% @products.each do |product| %>
>   <div class="product_item">
>     <span class="img"><%= image_tag product.image, size: "200x100" %></span>
>     <h1><%= product.name %></h1>
>     <!--<%= product.description %> Saved  this just incase we needed it-->
>     <%= number_to_currency(product.price) %>
>
>     <!-- Button that creates light box -->
>
>     <!-- here is the link for each product to open its modal -->
>
>     <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#more-info-<%= product.id %>" class="lightbox">More Info</a>
>
>     <!-- here is the modal content -->
>
>     <div id="more-info-<%= product.id %>"  class="modal fade" role="dialog">
>       <div class="modal-dialog">
>         <!-- Modal content-->
>         <div class="modal-content">
>           <div class="modal-header">
>             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
>             <h4 class="modal-title">More Info</h4>
>           </div>
>           <div class="modal-body">
>           </div>
>           <div class="modal-footer">
>             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
>           </div>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>
>   </div>
> <% end %>
> ```

- Or you can fetch these info by ajax and then show it on the modal

> ```
> <% @products.each do |product| %>
>     <div class="product_item">
>         <span class="img"><%= image_tag product.image, size: "200x100" %></span>
>         <h1><%= product.name %></h1>
>         <!--<%= product.description %> Saved  this just incase we needed it-->
>         <%= number_to_currency(product.price) %>
>         <!-- Button that creates light box -->
>         <button class="lightbox fetch-info" data-product-id="<%= product.id %>">More Info</button>
>     </div>
> <%end%>
> <!-- backdrop is the black background of lightbox -->
> <div class="backdrop"></div>
> <!-- the box that we need to plug information to -->
> <div class="box"><div class="close"></div>
>    <div id="fetch-result"></div>
> </div>
> ```

and then, create a JS to fetch the data:

```
$(".fetch-info").click(function() {
  var $input = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/product_info",
    data: {
      id: $input.data("product-id")
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $("#fetch-result").html(response);
    }
  });
});
```

Then, create an action to provide the product info:

```
def product_info
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  render layout: false
end
```

and create your view with your custom product info...

That's it!

Tip: if you choose the second option, you can improve by calling the action as JSON (fetch just the product info, and then in your success callback, you add the html there)

Comment: I've never done web development before this class, so I've never dealt with ajax, but wow! Thanks for the in-depth solutions! I'll try out the second option right now and let you know how it turned out. I like the second option better because I can then keep the front-end guy's design. I don't think he'd be too happy if I got rid of his stuff :D

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't seem to be working for me. I tried logging to the console but it turns out that the JS function isn't even being called. I put it in the application.js file. Is there a specific file name or location I have to put it in?

Comment: which option did you choose? render all data on the html or ajax? So, if you are beginner, I suggest you to choose the first way, so you won't need to create many things to render your data.

Comment: I chose the ajax option, but the syntax for the JS wasn't working for me. The JS code was put in my application.js file, and this is the syntax that worked for me: http://pastebin.com/ugLfKtmJ

Answer (score 0):

This is an index page, www.example.com/products. It is showing a list of the products and when clicked they will open a lightbox. What you are going to have to do is pass the id of each individual product into the button so that when the lightbox is opened it is showing the correct information for that product. Alessandro's code is not going to help you because product.attribute1 will not be defined.

Comment: Just noticed that you're right, i will delete my answer.